# PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: must be owner of database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Доброе утро!

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при запуске тестов, ругается что ошибка с владельцем базы данных, хотя раньше просто давались привелегии юзеру под бд с тестами, подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать.

База и пользователь заводились из под админа (postgres), после чего были даны все привилегии пользователю на базу.

Клинера нет.

Код ошибки: **PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  must be owner of database test**

Система:

**Rails: 5.0.0**

**Ruby: 2.3.1**

**PSQL: 9.5.3**

Comment: Из под какого пользователя создается база данных в pg? Из под какого пользователя запускаются тесты? И принципиально ли указывать пользователя для тестового окружения, нельзя ли просто убрать username и password из тестового окружения в database.yml и запускать тесты из под текущего пользователя?

Comment: Подозреваю, что используется что-то типа database-cleaner. Если так, то стоит попробовать стратегию `transaction` или `truncation`. Или выдать роли, указанной в `database.yml` для тестовой среды.

Comment: Найдите по трейсу, в каком коде это произошло. Исключения не прилетают из ниоткуда.